# Response code:Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to learn load testing with JMeter(Very new). Using the tutorial to Build a Web Test Plan on the JMeter website and another youtube tutorial. When I try to run JMeter this is error i get. Please help

Thread Name:USERS 1-1
Sample Start:2020-07-23 08:54:33 SAST
Load time:3151
Connect Time:3151
Latency:0
Size in bytes:2739
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:2739
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connect to 5z42l0gtij.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:80 [5z42l0gtij.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/54.171.7.7, 5z42l0gtij.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/34.252.147.236] failed: Connection refused: connect

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType:
DataEncoding: null

Answer (score 1):

Looking into your endpoint using [Nmap](https://nmap.org/):

[image]

it appears that port 80 is closed, you need to open it either in your [OS firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) or in [AWS Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html)

On the other hand port 443 is open which is default port for [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) so my expectation is that if you change "Protocol" in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))  you will be able to normally access your endpoint

[image]

Comment: can you please look into the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053225/how-to-dynamically-pass-json-values-in-jmeter-http-request-body... even I do not have much knowledge on Jmeter